# Error installing rvm on osx mavericks with brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

Thanks, Error installing rvm on osx mavericks tried all suggestion, but no matter what would happen.

```
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Installing RVM to /Users/coleschiffer/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/coleschiffer/.profile /Users/coleschiffer/.bashrc  /Users/coleschiffer/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/coleschiffer/.zlogin.
    RVM sourcing line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
Installation of RVM in /Users/coleschiffer/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/coleschiffer/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# coleschiffer,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

rvm 1.25.21 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

 Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system... ..
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libksba, openssl...
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libksba openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/coleschiffer/.rvm/log/1395513147_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libksba_openssl.log
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  82 > [[ -t 1 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  82 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_warn()  139 > printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_libs_install()  63 > case "$_system_version" in
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_libs_install()  70 > return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$ brew tap --repair
Pruned 0 dead formula
Tapped 129 formula
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$
```

thanks a million
I have been trying to install ruby on rails fro two days all help would be apriciated!

Comment: Have you tried `brew tap --repair` ?

Comment: Also you can install rubygems and do a gem install rails as well. I would try updating homebrew and doing the code mentioned above as well as brew doctor.

Comment: Maybe also try it as sudo

Comment: I tryed 'brew tap --repair' will try sudo and did try brew updating brew if you can see at the bottom thanks for the  help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you *need* to use brew for what you're trying to accomplish. The command you posted, `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` makes use of railsinstaller, as noted on the [rvm website](http://rvm.io/rvm/install).

If you look on the [railsinstaller website](http://railsinstaller.org/en), it currently says "Please do not run the installer on OSX Mavericks until further notice."

As CWitty mentioned, your best bet is probably to install rubygems and rails separately.

First install the stable version of RVM stable with ruby:

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Then [update rubygems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download):

`$ gem update --system          # may need to be administrator or root`

And finally [install rails using rubygems](http://rubyonrails.org/download):

`gem install rails`